# Remove error values from array

Tags: vba

Say that I have a UDF function:

```
 Dim arr() as variant, rng as range
 set rng = some range
 arr=rng
 Function=worksheetfunction.sum(arr)
```

If rng contains errors a values, how would I go about removing them from the arrray and not from the sheet?

I'd rather not do For each-statement looping through ranges in rng. I'd rather be able to remove them from the array.

This is more a general questions than anything.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to add them to a `Collection`, since these works better with dynamic size (you could also use `Scripting.Dictionary`. Then loop through the range, and add non-error cell values to the collection.

I know the example doesn't meet your requirement for not looping each element. But unless you have a specific reason to keep your data as a range, I don't really see an advatage of this. There are other data structures, which are more suited for further processing of the data.

Simple example:

```
Sub FindNonErrorCells()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim coll As Collection

    'Insert your range here
    Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C1:C5")

    Set coll = New Collection

    For Each cell In rng
        If Not IsError(cell) Then
            coll.Add cell.Value
        End If
    Next cell

End Sub
```